# Python Graphene. Authorization error handling

Tags: vue.js, graphene-python

I have the following environment:

**Frontend**

@vue/cli 4.1.2

vue-apollo 3.0.2

**Backend**

python 3.8

django 3.0.2

graphene-django 2.8.0

django-graphql-jwt 0.3.0

My problem is handle the auth errors when the token has expired. For example, if I request the query `me` when the token is expired:

```
def resolve_me(root, info):
    user = info.context.user
    if user.is_anonymous:
        raise GraphQLError('Authentication failure!!')
    return user
```

in the link of the apollo client receive a 200 and the `networkError` object is empty and `graphQLErrors` object don't provide the status code.

how you manage this scenario? 
Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this comment https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/142#issuecomment-221290862

> As far as I can tell from the GraphQL spec there is no discussion of http response codes at all. The status codes of HTTP are strongly tied to rest principles. It's not clear to me whether GraphQL APIs should distinguish between 2XX and 4XX status codes.
>
> Most notably, you can batch multiple mutations into the same request to the server. If one successfully creates a resource (201), one mutates a resource (200), one fails validation (400) and another the target object does not exists (404), what should the return value from the API be?
>
> At the moment, GraphQL APIs seem to err on the side of 200 unless the server blows up, in which case 500.